# How to specify multiple random slopes in glmmPQL (MASS package)?

Tags: r, random-effects-model, glmm

I would like to specify more than one random effect in a generalized linear mixed model with glmmPQL (MASS package). Currently I am using the data from Heck, Thomas and Tabata (2012).

So what I would like to achieve is to prove, if the slopes of the level 1-predictors (femal, minor and lowses) vary between the level 2 units.

Is this the right code to do so? 
If not - How can I specify multiple random effects simultaneously?

```
PQL<-glmmPQL(readprof~female+minor+lowses+schcomp+smallsch, random=(~1|schcode/minor/female/lowses), family = binomial(link = logit), data = Heck)
```

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> So what I would like to achieve is to prove, if the slopes of the level 1-predictors (femal, minor and lowses) vary between the level 2 units.

I'm new to glmmPQL and mixed-effects models, and I"m not entirely sure what you mean by "level 2 units" here, so I can't check that your model is constructed properly. However, I think I can help you with your question:

> How can I specify multiple random effects simultaneously?

According to the glmmPQL [documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/BradleyTerry2/versions/1.0-7/topics/glmmPQL), you need to create a matrix of the formulas to input multiple random effects.

```
PQL<-glmmPQL(readprof~female+minor+lowses+schcomp+smallsch, random=list(schcode = ~1, minor = ~1, female = ~1, lowses = ~1), family = binomial(link = logit), data = Heck)
```

I found the above info at [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32038355/r-glmm-glmer-vs-glmmpql).

Slashes are used for [covariates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47798857/correct-syntax-for-covariate-in-mixed-models-or-asterisk-vs-slash-in-lme-lmer) in a model, rather than just allowing you to input the multiple random effects. You can see how they work in the link.

I hope this helps.